# Split grouped timestamped log data using timestamp itself as splitter?

Tags: java

I wanted to write code which could read a log file and split it into multiple events, using the timestamp as the splitter (since every log entry begins with a timestamp). A sample of the logs I want to split is given below. I'd also like to keep the timestamp itself.

So if this is my input:

```
01 Aug 2016 04:48:13,311 ERROR [pool-2-thread-12436] com.orders.queue.OrdersQueueWorker - x-company-requestid=836ac8b6-515d-4414-b4c6-ddd8a52ef497-sqs service_name=orders_v3 Exception while calling /purchases: x-company-status : UNKNOWN_ERROR response status: Internal Server Error 
01 Aug 2016 04:48:13,311  WARN [pool-2-thread-12436] com.orders.queue.OrdersQueueWorker - x-company-requestid=836ac8b6-515d-4414-b4c6-ddd8a52ef497-sqs service_name=orders_v3 Failed to process order, will be re-tried: ADD2500051FR
01 Aug 2016 04:48:13,332  INFO [pool-2-thread-12436] com.delegate - x-company-requestid=836ac8b6-515d-4414-b4c6-ddd8a52ef497-sqs service_name=orders_v3 Getting Email from Primary email
01 Aug 2016 04:48:13,363  WARN [pool-2-thread-12436] com.queue.SQSQueueWorker - x-company-requestid=836ac8b6-515d-4414-b4c6-ddd8a52ef497-sqs service_name=orders_v3 Message processing failed QueueMessage [payload=ADD2500051FR, delaySeconds=0, sqsId=51f70e3f-554a-463b-8384-0b2c25a90450, stringAttributes={features=adac2911-0578-4bcd-b8c3-783481a48e1d, accept-language=FR_FR, request-id=836ac8b6-515d-4414-b4c6-ddd8a52ef497}]
com.orders.exception.orderserviceException: Error in Calling PUT purchase from main service 
    at com.OrderServiceDelegate.handleInternalServerErrors(OrderServiceDelegate.java:352)
    at com.OrderServiceDelegate.sendOrderForProcessing_aroundBody0(OrderServiceDelegate.java:113)
    at com.OrderServiceDelegate.sendOrderForProcessing_aroundBody1$advice(OrderServiceDelegate.java:37)
    at com.OrderServiceDelegate.sendOrderForProcessing(OrderServiceDelegate.java:1)
    at com.orders.queue.OrdersQueueWorker.doWork(OrdersQueueWorker.java:168)
    at com.queue.SQSQueueWorker.lambda$0(SQSQueueWorker.java:149)
    at com.queue.SQSQueueWorker.dt_access$492(SQSQueueWorker.java)
    at com.queue.SQSQueueWorker$$dtt$$Lambda$8/852112146.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
01 Aug 2016 04:48:13,365  INFO [pool-2-thread-12436] com.queue.SQSQueueWorker - x-company-requestid=836ac8b6-515d-4414-b4c6-ddd8a52ef497-sqs service_name=orders_v3 Order will be re-tried after 300 seconds: ADD2500051FR 
01 Aug 2016 04:48:15,600  INFO [myScheduler-3] com.queue.SQSQueueWorker - x-company-requestid=sqs-worker service_name=orders_v3 Processing messages message_number=1
01 Aug 2016 04:48:15,600  INFO [pool-2-thread-12436] com.queue.SQSQueueWorker - x-company-requestid=836ac8b6-515d-4414-b4c6-ddd8a52ef497-sqs service_name=orders_v3 Received msg from SQS:QueueMessage [payload=428CB476547214700268914651663, delaySeconds=0, sqsId=7f4dcbbe-90c4-4e56-b4ab-50332597b5d8, stringAttributes={features=FIS-JEM, accept-language=EN_US, request-id=a2c31da4-517f-40ec-8587-624f97393659}]
```

Then my output should be (the horizontal line depicts where one entry ends and another begins):

```
01 Aug 2016 04:48:13,311 ERROR [pool-2-thread-12436] com.orders.queue.OrdersQueueWorker - x-company-requestid=836ac8b6-515d-4414-b4c6-ddd8a52ef497-sqs service_name=orders_v3 Exception while calling /purchases: x-company-status : UNKNOWN_ERROR response status: Internal Server Error
//--------------------------------------------
01 Aug 2016 04:48:13,311  WARN [pool-2-thread-12436] com.orders.queue.OrdersQueueWorker - x-company-requestid=836ac8b6-515d-4414-b4c6-ddd8a52ef497-sqs service_name=orders_v3 Failed to process order, will be re-tried: ADD2500051FR
//--------------------------------------------
01 Aug 2016 04:48:13,332  INFO [pool-2-thread-12436] com.delegate - x-company-requestid=836ac8b6-515d-4414-b4c6-ddd8a52ef497-sqs service_name=orders_v3 Getting Email from Primary email
//--------------------------------------------
01 Aug 2016 04:48:13,363  WARN [pool-2-thread-12436] com.queue.SQSQueueWorker - x-company-requestid=836ac8b6-515d-4414-b4c6-ddd8a52ef497-sqs service_name=orders_v3 Message processing failed QueueMessage [payload=ADD2500051FR, delaySeconds=0, sqsId=51f70e3f-554a-463b-8384-0b2c25a90450, stringAttributes={features=adac2911-0578-4bcd-b8c3-783481a48e1d, accept-language=FR_FR, request-id=836ac8b6-515d-4414-b4c6-ddd8a52ef497}]
com.orders.exception.orderserviceException: Error in Calling PUT purchase from main service 
    at com.OrderServiceDelegate.handleInternalServerErrors(OrderServiceDelegate.java:352)
    at com.OrderServiceDelegate.sendOrderForProcessing_aroundBody0(OrderServiceDelegate.java:113)
    at com.OrderServiceDelegate.sendOrderForProcessing_aroundBody1$advice(OrderServiceDelegate.java:37)
    at com.OrderServiceDelegate.sendOrderForProcessing(OrderServiceDelegate.java:1)
    at com.orders.queue.OrdersQueueWorker.doWork(OrdersQueueWorker.java:168)
    at com.queue.SQSQueueWorker.lambda$0(SQSQueueWorker.java:149)
    at com.queue.SQSQueueWorker.dt_access$492(SQSQueueWorker.java)
    at com.queue.SQSQueueWorker$$dtt$$Lambda$8/852112146.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
//--------------------------------------------
01 Aug 2016 04:48:13,365  INFO [pool-2-thread-12436] com.queue.SQSQueueWorker - x-company-requestid=836ac8b6-515d-4414-b4c6-ddd8a52ef497-sqs service_name=orders_v3 Order will be re-tried after 300 seconds: ADD2500051FR
//--------------------------------------------
01 Aug 2016 04:48:15,600  INFO [myScheduler-3] com.queue.SQSQueueWorker - x-company-requestid=sqs-worker service_name=orders_v3 Processing messages message_number=1
//--------------------------------------------
01 Aug 2016 04:48:15,600  INFO [pool-2-thread-12436] com.queue.SQSQueueWorker - x-company-requestid=836ac8b6-515d-4414-b4c6-ddd8a52ef497-sqs service_name=orders_v3 Received msg from SQS:QueueMessage [payload=428CB476547214700268914651663, delaySeconds=0, sqsId=7f4dcbbe-90c4-4e56-b4ab-50332597b5d8, stringAttributes={features=FIS-JEM, accept-language=EN_US, request-id=a2c31da4-517f-40ec-8587-624f97393659}]
```

I imagine some sort of regex would be needed, but I have no experience in using regex to do such a split through Java code.

I also found the following related question, but I didn't understand the solution suggested there:
[java regex: capture multiline sequence between tokens](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2515029/java-regex-capture-multiline-sequence-between-tokens)

Comment: This could be done with a `BufferedReader` and a `StringBuilder`.

Answer (score 0):

The following code uses the log you supplied and produces your desired output. I've included comments in the code that explain the program flow.

**Code:**

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;


public class Driver {
    private static final String LINE_BREAK = System.lineSeparator();

    // path to the logfile
    private static final String LOG_FILE = "xin/xin.log";

    // The regex below matches lines that begin with "00 Mth 0000 00:00:00,000".
    private static Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^[0-9][0-9]\\s[A-Z][a-z][a-z]\\s[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]\\s[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9],[0-9][0-9][0-9]");

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BufferedReader reader = null;
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = "";
        boolean firstRun = true;

        try {
            // instantiated the buffered reader
            reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File(LOG_FILE)));
        } catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // loop until all lines are read from log file 
        while(true) {
            try {
                // get next line from log file
                line = reader.readLine();
                // if no more content in log file then break out of loop
                if(line == null) {
                    break;
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            // we don't want a line-break before the first line
            if(firstRun) {
                firstRun = false;
                // append the first line to the string builder
                sb.append(line);
            } else {
                // we've handled the first line, so now we
                // append a line-break to the string builder
                // before appending the next line
                sb.append(LINE_BREAK);

                // if the line matches the timestamp pattern then
                // append another line-break
                if(pattern.matcher(line).find()) {
                    sb.append(LINE_BREAK);
                }
                // add the line to the string builder
                sb.append(line);
            }

        }

        try {
            // close the buffered reader
            reader.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // print string builder contents to standard out
        System.out.println(sb.toString());
    }

}
```

**Output:**

```
01 Aug 2016 04:48:13,311 ERROR [pool-2-thread-12436] com.orders.queue.OrdersQueueWorker - x-company-requestid=836ac8b6-515d-4414-b4c6-ddd8a52ef497-sqs service_name=orders_v3 Exception while calling /purchases: x-company-status : UNKNOWN_ERROR response status: Internal Server Error 

01 Aug 2016 04:48:13,311  WARN [pool-2-thread-12436] com.orders.queue.OrdersQueueWorker - x-company-requestid=836ac8b6-515d-4414-b4c6-ddd8a52ef497-sqs service_name=orders_v3 Failed to process order, will be re-tried: ADD2500051FR

01 Aug 2016 04:48:13,332  INFO [pool-2-thread-12436] com.delegate - x-company-requestid=836ac8b6-515d-4414-b4c6-ddd8a52ef497-sqs service_name=orders_v3 Getting Email from Primary email

01 Aug 2016 04:48:13,363  WARN [pool-2-thread-12436] com.queue.SQSQueueWorker - x-company-requestid=836ac8b6-515d-4414-b4c6-ddd8a52ef497-sqs service_name=orders_v3 Message processing failed QueueMessage [payload=ADD2500051FR, delaySeconds=0, sqsId=51f70e3f-554a-463b-8384-0b2c25a90450, stringAttributes={features=adac2911-0578-4bcd-b8c3-783481a48e1d, accept-language=FR_FR, request-id=836ac8b6-515d-4414-b4c6-ddd8a52ef497}]
com.orders.exception.orderserviceException: Error in Calling PUT purchase from main service 
    at com.OrderServiceDelegate.handleInternalServerErrors(OrderServiceDelegate.java:352)
    at com.OrderServiceDelegate.sendOrderForProcessing_aroundBody0(OrderServiceDelegate.java:113)
    at com.OrderServiceDelegate.sendOrderForProcessing_aroundBody1$advice(OrderServiceDelegate.java:37)
    at com.OrderServiceDelegate.sendOrderForProcessing(OrderServiceDelegate.java:1)
    at com.orders.queue.OrdersQueueWorker.doWork(OrdersQueueWorker.java:168)
    at com.queue.SQSQueueWorker.lambda$0(SQSQueueWorker.java:149)
    at com.queue.SQSQueueWorker.dt_access$492(SQSQueueWorker.java)
    at com.queue.SQSQueueWorker$$dtt$$Lambda$8/852112146.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

01 Aug 2016 04:48:13,365  INFO [pool-2-thread-12436] com.queue.SQSQueueWorker - x-company-requestid=836ac8b6-515d-4414-b4c6-ddd8a52ef497-sqs service_name=orders_v3 Order will be re-tried after 300 seconds: ADD2500051FR 

01 Aug 2016 04:48:15,600  INFO [myScheduler-3] com.queue.SQSQueueWorker - x-company-requestid=sqs-worker service_name=orders_v3 Processing messages message_number=1

01 Aug 2016 04:48:15,600  INFO [pool-2-thread-12436] com.queue.SQSQueueWorker - x-company-requestid=836ac8b6-515d-4414-b4c6-ddd8a52ef497-sqs service_name=orders_v3 Received msg from SQS:QueueMessage [payload=428CB476547214700268914651663, delaySeconds=0, sqsId=7f4dcbbe-90c4-4e56-b4ab-50332597b5d8, stringAttributes={features=FIS-JEM, accept-language=EN_US, request-id=a2c31da4-517f-40ec-8587-624f97393659}]
```

If you need any additional help, then just leave a comment on this answer and I'll try my best to help.